# C# Sort list while also returning the original index positions?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, collections

I'm interested in sorting a collection, but also returning an index which can be used to map to the original position in the collection (before the sort).

Let me give an example to be more clear:

```
List<int> A = new List<int>(){3,2,1};
List<int> B;
List<int> idx;

Sort(A,out B,out idx);
```

After which:

```
A = [3,2,1] 
B = [1,2,3]
idx = [2,1,0]
```

So that the relationship between A,B,idx is:

`A[i] == B[ idx[i] ]` , for i = 0...2

Does C#/.Net have any built in mechanism to make this easy to implement?

Thanks.

Comment: I note that what you're looking for is called a *permutation*. The task of sorting can be characterized as essentially the task of identifying which of all the possible permutations of a given array produces a sorted array.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It can be done quite easily using Linq.

- Convert your list into a new list of pairs (object, original index of object).

  Sort the new list by the first item in the pair

  Extract the sorted list and the original indices.

Here's some code to demonstrate the principle:

```
List<int> A = new List<int>() { 3, 2, 1 };

var sorted = A
    .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, i))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();

List<int> B = sorted.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
List<int> idx = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

I think this gives A[idx[i]] = B[i], but that hopefully is good enough for you.

Answer (score 27):

While Mark Byers provided you a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760185/c-sort-list-while-also-returning-the-original-index-positions/1760202#1760202) using LINQ, I want to show you another solution using the .NET Framework.

There is an overload of [`Array.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3.aspx) that will do this for you:

```
int[] a = new[] { 3, 2, 1 };
int[] p = new[] { 0, 1, 2 };

Array.Sort(a, p);

Assert.IsTrue(a.SequenceEquals(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Assert.IsTrue(p.SequenceEquals(new[] { 2, 1, 0 }));
```

Thus, here is a generic method meeting your specification that leverages this overload:

```
void Sort<T>(
    List<T> input,
    out List<T> output,
    out List<int> permutation,
    IComparer<T> comparer
) {
    if(input == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("input"); }
    if(input.Count == 0) {
        // give back empty lists
        output = new List<T>(); 
        permutation = new List<int>();
        return;
    }
    if(comparer == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer"); }
    int[] items = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count).ToArray();
    T[] keys = input.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(keys, items, comparer);
    output = keys.ToList();
    permutation = items.ToList();   
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using `Comparer<T>.Default` instead of throwing an `ArgumentNullExcpetion` if `comparer` is `null`.  Otherwise, +1 for a complete, direct, and performant solution.

Comment: @P Daddy: Great suggestion, although I would handle that by providing an overload `Sort<T>(List<T>, out List<T>, out List<int>)` that calls the above method with `Comparer<T>.Default` as the `comparer`.

Comment: I found this question because I wanted to sort an array getting the indices, but I was just using the indices to reorder a different array the same way. How pleased I was to find I could just do `Array.Sort(arr1, arr2);` instead; thanks!

Answer (score 8):

a somehow more elegant approach using lambda

```
Array.Sort<int>(idx, (a, b) => A[a].CompareTo(A[b]));
```

this gives u idx array from the A array

Comment: `idx` has to be an array, preassigned by `Enumerable.Range(0, A.Count).ToArray()` instead of an empty list. And to complete your answer, `B = A.OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(idx, A.IndexOf(i))).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

As for now, you can also utilize anonymous types or value tuples instead of `KeyValuePair`. It will provide more precise naming and make your code more readable:

Anonymous types (C# 3.0):

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>() { 3, 2, 1 };

var sorted = arr
    .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, OriginalIndex = i }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();

int originalIndexOfTheSmallestItem = sorted[0].OriginalIndex;

List<int> B = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
List<int> idx = sorted.Select(x => x.OriginalIndex).ToList();
```

Value tuples (C# 7.0):

```
List<int> arr = new List<int>() { 3, 2, 1 };

var sorted = arr
    .Select((x, i) => (Value: x, OriginalIndex: i))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();

int originalIndexOfTheSmallestItem = sorted[0].OriginalIndex;

List<int> B = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
List<int> idx = sorted.Select(x => x.OriginalIndex).ToList();
```

The difference is that you can return value tuple from your method and use it, but anonymous type can only be used within this method.

Answer (score 0):

I typically write a specific function when needed. Less versatile but simpler. For example:

```
static int[] ArgSort(List<double> lst)
{
  int n = lst.Count;
  int[] idxs = new int[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    idxs[i] = i;
  double[] arr = lst.ToArray();
  Array.Sort(arr, idxs);  // sort idxs based on arr vals
  return idxs;
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?