# How to sort two arrays by same index?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have 2 arrays. I want to sort them by same index number. For example I have these:

```
int[] a = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20};
int[] b = {12, 29, 37, 85, 63, 11};

Array.Sort(b); // Now, b is -> b = {11, 12, 29, 37, 63, 85}
```

I want to sort a by b's index -> `a = {20, 120, 60, 50, 30, 40}`

If I have also string array `c -> c = {"b", "u", "r", "s", "a", "1"}`

I want to sort c by b's index -> `c = {"1", "b", "u", "r", "a", "s"}`

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760185/c-sharp-sort-list-while-also-returning-the-original-index-positions

Comment: This is useful for me. Array.Sort(b,d);

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Array.Sort<TKey, TValue>(TKey[] keys, TValue[] items)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f.aspx) that accepts two input arrays, one is the array of keys, the other is the array of items to sort using those keys. Here, for you, `b` is your keys and `a` is your items.

Thus:

```
Array.Sort(b, a);
```

will use the keys of `b` to sort the items of `a`.

> I want to sort `c` by `b`'s index -> `c = {"1", "b", "u", "r", "a", "s"}`

Not clear exactly what you mean. At the same time as you sort `a` using `b`? If so, it's easy as we can still use the above. Zip `a` and `c` into a single array of `Tuple<int, string>`.

```
var d = a.Zip(c, (x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y)).ToArray();
```

Then:

```
Array.Sort(b, d);
```

as above. Then extract the pieces:

```
a = d.Select(z => z.Item1).ToArray();
c = d.Select(z => z.Item2).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, if you need to sort a lot of arrays using the same set of keys:

```
int[] indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, b.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(b, indexes);
```

Now you can use `indexes` to sort all the arrays you need. For example:

```
a = indexes.Select(index => a[index]).ToArray();
c = indexes.Select(index => c[index]).ToArray();
```

etc. as needed.

Possibly some minor coding errors here. No compiler handy.

Comment: This is great, but I can't get it working on .NET Standard before version 1.3 due to double[] not implementing System.Collections.IComparer.

Answer (score 1):

```
// a dirty and inefficient way of doing it, 
// but should give you a heads up to get started

    // you obviously dont want to modify array b, so making a copy
    int[] c = Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);
    // now apply a sort on 'c' and apply the same operation on 'a' when modifying 'c'
    // -> applying a bubble sort - > inefficient
    for( int i = 0; i < c.length ; i ++) {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < c.length - 1; j ++) {
            if(c[j] > c [j+1]) {
                c[j] = c[j] + c[j+1];
                c[j+1] = c[j] - c[j+1];
                c[j] = c[j] - c[j+1];

                // apply the same to a
                a[j] = a[j] + a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = a[j] - a[j+1];
                a[j] = a[j] - a[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
```