# c# Sorting 2 arrays while having same number in index

Tags: c#, sorting

I have 2 arrays:

```
int[] x1 = { 1, 2, 1, 2 };
int[] x2 = { 3, 1, 2, 3 };
```

and after sorting them with

```
Array.Sort(x1, x2);
```

the arrays look like this:

```
int[] x1 = { 1, 1, 2, 2 };
int[] x2 = { 3, 2, 1, 3 };
```

But I want array x2 to look like this:

```
{3,2,3,1}
```

The problem is, if .sort sees the same number in first array(index, here x1) it will just sort the same numbers as they went after each other and won't looks at the x2 array, which I want it to do. So, is it somehow possible to sort it this way?

Comment: So you want to order by column1, then order by descending column2? Please show us the arrays you have - give us code to work with! Also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: If the data is related the first thing is to combine it into one collections like a `List<Tuple<int,int>>` instead of two separate arrays.

Comment: @Gavin It appears the 2 arrays are coupled, and IMO he should follow @juharr's suggestion. Logically he has, `[1,3]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,1]`, and `[2,3]`, and he wants equal column one values to be sorted in reverse based on their column 2 values, i.e., `[2,3]` should be before `[2,1]`.

Comment: yeah, I'm sorry, I mistook row with column. Array1 = { 1, 2, 1, 2} and Array2 = {3, 1, 2, 3}, after Array.Sort(Array1, Array2) it looks like this: Array1 = {1, 1, 2, 2} and Array2 = { 3, 2, 1, 3} and I want the Array2 to look like this: {3, 2, 3, 1}. So, yeah, I want the Array2 to be sorted descending but to still have it attached to Array1 in which it will only swap same numbers, so it wont really affect the orderliness of Array1. Thanks for editing my post and helping me, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: yes, exactly what @Quantic said, thanks

Comment: You need to [edit] your post with this info, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: Since you've already searched for possible solutions (probably using one of search engines - Google, Yahoo, Bing - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+sort+two+arrays) please clarify why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085927/how-to-sort-two-arrays-by-same-index did not work for you.

Comment: the lazy less efficient LINQ way `Array2 = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, Array2.Length) orderby Array1[i], Array2[i] descending select Array2[i]).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 arrays like this:

```
int[] x1 = { 1, 2, 1, 2}; 
int[] x2 = {3, 1, 2, 3};
```

The first thing I would do is to join them together and apply the ordering. This is pretty simple with some Linq:

```
var joined = x1.Zip(x2, (a, b) => new { a, b })
   .OrderBy(x => x.a)
   .ThenByDescending(x => x.b);
```

Now you can split them back up into the constituent arrays:

```
x1 = joined.Select(x => x.a).ToArray();
x2 = joined.Select(x => x.b).ToArray();
```