# Reforming integer range to a smaller integer range (Unity (C#))

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, i have a set of integers in an list

```
public List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 11 }
```

what i am wanting to do is change those numbers so they are ordered between 0 and 6, to set as siblingindexs.

and then would be changed to become

```
public List<int> newArrangedNumbers = new List<int>() {0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6}
```

But im really not sure how to do this... Anyone know?

P.S. i cant rearrange the numbers because then i would lose track of the game objects since the numbers themselves aren't actually in an array, but i have gameobjects in an array, and i find the "SortIndex" of each gameobject, which are the numbers from above, the order of the numbers in the array is actually the order of GameObjects in the array, which i need to keep the same.

Edit: i also cannot change them to float values because for some reason, when using SetSiblingIndex(int), you have to integers, you cant use floats

Edit 2: i am NOT trying to sort the numbers, i am trying to CONVERT the numbers from 3-11 into 0-6 in ORDER

From:

```
{3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 11}
```

To:

```
{0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6}
```

Edit 3: Here is my script for testing

```
List<int> Indexs = new List<int>() { 4, 7, 56, 9, 65, 67, 8, 3, 6 };

        var sorted = Indexs.Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, i)).OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToList();
        List<int> newArrangedNumbers = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();

        for(int i = 0; i < newArrangedNumbers.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(Indexs[i] + " : " + newArrangedNumbers[i]);
        }
```

When i only had 7 (0-6) indexs in the "Indexs" List it worked fine, but when i added any more, it started giving me the incorrect numbers

This is what it gives with this

[image]

Comment: So is what you need a simple conversion  from `numbers` to `newArrangedNumbers`? I assume the number 0-6 are determined by the increasing order of `numbers`?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to change the 3-11 numbers into 0-6, but i need them to stay in the same order

Comment: From what I've gathered from looking at your post, it looks like you are dealing with indexes. You aren't shrinking your numbers, rather those numbers are the indexes sorted in the input list.

Comment: Alright, so i apologise, i didnt understand the code you guys were writing fully and so it was confusing, my original goal was not to get the indexs, i do see how you got there though, and yes that would work for me, my only issue now is that unity doesnt have an OrderBy classifer that i can find.

Comment: Okay, so i have run into a new problem, it worked, but when i tried adding a 7th item into the list, it messed up again... it put them in the wrong orders.. is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good method to achieve your desired output from this stack form [C# Sort list while also returning the original index positions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760185/c-sharp-sort-list-while-also-returning-the-original-index-positions)

The modified code for your solution is below.

```
//The original list
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 11 };

var sorted = numbers
    .Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(x, i))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();

//The sorted list
List<int> numbersSorted = sorted.Select(x => x.Key).ToList();

//List of indexes sorted based on the list above
List<int> newArrangedNumbers = sorted.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

**Edit**

Since you sort the list, but also retrieve the sorted indexes based on the list you just sorted, you aren't going to have any mixup with your game objects.

Comment: I appriciate the response, but i am trying to get from the numbers list to the arrangedNumbers list, converting the numbers 3-11 into 0-6 respectively

Comment: Are you not sorting the list, but showing the indexes of that sorted list?

Comment: I am not trying to sort the list, i am trying to convert the indexs from a range of 3 - 11 (from the first list), into a new list (with the same indexs) that is instead only from 0-6, as in, 3 would become 0, 6 would become 1, 7 would become 2, etc...

Comment: @AaronJones, the initial define should be { 3, 7, 6, 9, 8, 10, 11 }, not the index positions.{ 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6 } is the desired output of newArrangedNumbers

Comment: Thanks Dragonel, your right! I made the changes to my post.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding a few comments to the code for those who don't easily read Linq

Comment: Alright, so i tested this and it works great, but when i added a 7th index into the List, it messed it up and didnt give me them in the right order, is there something im missing, cause i typed it the exact way you have it on here?

Comment: Are you adding a new element to the original list? In order to sort the list and get the new list of sorted indexes, all lists need to have the same number of objects in them.

Comment: Are you just adding another item to the original list, or adding an actual Unity object?

Comment: well, yes, i am technically doing both, since the array is a temporary list i created that involves the GameObjects, i created another game object, and when ia dded it, from my other code it automatically gets added into my crappy sorting system, my sorting system outputs the List<int> which is what i used and needed to adjust in my original post, when i add another element, it works, but it gives me really weird numbers

Comment: if you want to sort a list from least to greatest, you can just say `numbers.Sort()`

Comment: im not trying to sort it, i tried to do the same thing i did in my original post, just my list that i used for input, has more indexs then it did before

Comment: I'm sorry I can't be of more help, but I think your problem might lie more with Unity rather than c#. I've tested my above code with longer lists and it works perfectly fine. If I had to guess, it might be something with your Unity objects not being added to your list correctly.

Comment: Okay, ill do a bit more experimenting, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to find positions of each element in a sorted list of the same items.

So sort and find where element is and assign the index. Code sample below assumes unique numbers:

```
var sorted = numbers.OrderBy(x=>x).ToArray();
var result = new int[numbers.Count];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
{
    var index = number.IndexOf(sorted[i]);
    result[index] = i;
}
```

Notes

- for anything about 5-10 items I'd use dictionary instead of `IndexOf` if you want to stick with this code.
- if numbers are not unique or performance is critical you need to use solution by Aaron Jones that eventually will track original indexes even if it is harder to understand.

Comment: I edited my post to try to clear it up, i am NOT trying to sort the numbers, i am trying to convert from the numbers 3-11, to 0-6, while keeping each one in the same place

Comment: Okay, i may have misread what your goal was, but either way, i am unable to use these solutions as unity does not have a function ".OrderBy" in Lists, meaning i am unable to get a result or even compile my code, am i missing a using reference?

Comment: You need to be `using System.Linq`

Comment: Okay, sorry all for the confusion, i wasn't understand what you were trying to do, i thought you were just trying to sort the array by values, i am still learning c#, so i apologise, i got it working thanks to you guys, thanks so much!